# MVC Controllers get value of 'Checkboxlist'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkboxlist

I'm probably a idiot here but I'm having problems getting the value of whether or not a checkbox is checked/selected or not. Here's what I've got so far:

In my Model:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Insurers
{
  get
    { 
      var list = new List<SelectListItem>();
      string zInsurersList = "Age UK,Be Wiser,Call Connection,Churchill,Sainsbury's,Direct Line,Hastings Direct,LV=,Nationwide,RIAS,Swinton";
      string[] zInsurers = zInsurersList.Split(',');
      foreach (string aInsurer in zInsurers)
      {
        list.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = aInsurer, Value = aInsurer, Selected=false});
      }
      return list;
    }
  }
}
```

And my view:

```
@foreach (var insurer in @Model.Insurers)
{
  var zInsurer = insurer.Text;
  var zValue = insurer.Value;
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 120px; height: 35px;"><span id="@zInsurer">@zInsurer</span></td>
    <td style="width: 40px; height: 35px;"><input id="@zInsurer" type="checkbox" name="@zInsurer"></td>
  </tr>
}
```

So in my controller I'm trying to loop the list and get the value of whether or not the user has selected the option:

```
foreach (var item in model.Insurers)
{
  //if (item.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
  //string controlVal = ((SelectListItem)item).Selected.ToString();
  zInsurers = zInsurers + item.Text + " " + ((SelectListItem)item).Selected.ToString() + "<br/>";
}
```

But the value always returns false.

Could someone spare a few mins to highlight my stupidity please?

Thanks,

Craig

Comment: Possibly a binding issue - if you use `for (int i = 0; i < Model.Insurers.Count; i++)` in the View instead of the foreach, and use something like: `CheckBoxFor(x => x.Insurers[i].Text)`.  I don't understand why you pass a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` when you're not actually displaying a `SelectList` though...

Comment: Hi Mark, In truth I don't know myself. I'm beginning in this sort of thing and I've copied over some code that I'm attempting to butcher. it could be that I'm going down the complete wrong road.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do it. I normally add **String Array** in model to collect selected values.

```
public string[] SelectedInsurers { get; set; }

<input type="checkbox" name="SelectedInsurers" value="@insurer.Value" />
```

Here is the sample code -

### MyModel

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string[] SelectedInsurers { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Insurers
    {
        get
        {
            var list = new List<SelectListItem>();
            string zInsurersList = "Age UK,Be Wiser,Call Connection,Churchill,Sainsbury's,Direct Line,Hastings Direct,LV=,Nationwide,RIAS,Swinton";
            string[] zInsurers = zInsurersList.Split(',');
            foreach (string aInsurer in zInsurers)
            {
                list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = aInsurer, Value = aInsurer, Selected = false });
            }

            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

### Action Methods

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new MyModel());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
{
    return View();
}
```

### View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    foreach (var insurer in @Model.Insurers)
    {
        <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedInsurers" value="@insurer.Value" /> @insurer.Text<br/>
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Post Back" />
}
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: @SxChoc It is a job of ModelBinder. DefaultModelBinder is very powerful and complex; I suggest you to read Adam Freeman's MVC book.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your property `Insurers` should not be `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (tha'ts for binding a collection to a dropdownlist), and in any case, that kind of logic does not belong in a `getter` (and whats the point of creating a comma delimited string and then splitting it? - just create an array of strings in the first place!).  Its not really clear exactly what you trying to do, but you should be creating a view model and doing it the MVC way and making use of its model binding features

View model

```
public class InsurerVM
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
  // This should be loaded from some data source
  string[] insurers = new string[] { "Age UK", "Be Wiser", "Call Connection" };
  List<InsurerVM> model = insurers.Select(i => new InsurerVM() { Name = i }).ToList();
  return View(model);
}
```

View

```
@model List<InsurerVM>
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
  {
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Name)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].IsSelected)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.[i].IsSelected, Model[i].Name)
  }
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Post method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(IEnumerable<InsurerVM> model)
{
  // loop each item to get the insurer name and the value indicating if it has been selected
  foreach(InsurerVM insurer in model)
  {
    ....
  }
}
```

In reality, `Insurers` would be an object with an `ID` and other properties so it can be identified and have a relationship with other entities.

As to why you code is not working. Your property does not have a setter so nothing that posted back could be bound anyway. All the method is doing is initializing your model then calling the getter which creates a new `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (identical to the one you sent to the view in the first place). Not that it would have mattered anyway, your checkboxes have `name` attributes `name="Age_UK"`, `name=Be_Wiser"` etc which have absolutely no relationship to your model so cant be bound

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks loads for this :) I'm coming over from a webforms background and I'm finding the whole model binding black magic at the moment! You're definitely right about the string array. I'd confused myself into oblivion! 

Fantasic support from everyone. Marvellous

Answer (score 0):

That is because the modelbinding can't process your values.

You should look into model binding.

Try something like this:

```
  @for (var countInsurer = 0; Model.Insurers.Count > countInsurer++)
                    {
                        var zInsurer = insurer.Text;
                        var zValue = insurer.Value;
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 120px; height: 35px;"><span id="@zInsurer">@zInsurer</span></td>
                            <td style="width: 40px; height: 35px;">@Html.CheckBoxFor(m=> Model.Insurers[countInsurer], new {name = zInsurer})</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @for(int i = 0; i < Model.List.Count; i++)
                            {
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.List[i].IsChecked, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                @Model.List[i].Name
                                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.List[i].ID)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.List[i].Name)
                            <br />
                            }
```

**in controller**

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    foreach (var item in objDetail.List)
                    {
                        if (item.IsChecked)
                        {  
                            sb.Append(item.Value + ",");
                        }
                    }    
                    ViewBag.Loc = "Your preferred work locations are " + sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score -1):

I Get Module And Right from Module and Rights Table How to Send All Data To RoleRight Table All Checkbox value

```
public class RoleRightModel
{        
    public ModuleModel _ModuleModel { get; set; }
    public RightsModel _RightsModel { get; set; }
    public RolesModel _RolesModel { get; set; }
    public List<ModuleModel> _ModuleModelList { get; set; }
    public List<RightsModel> _RightsModelList { get; set; }
    public List<RolesModel> _RolesModelList { get; set; }
    public List<RoleRightModel> _RoleRightModelList { get; set; }
    public int RoleRightID { get; set; }
    public int RoleID { get; set; }
    public int ModuleID { get; set; }
    public int FormMode { get; set; }
    public int RightCode { get; set; }
    public bool? RowInternal { get; set; }
    public byte? IsAuthorised { get; set; }
    public int? CreationID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }
    public int? LastModificationID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastModificationDate { get; set; }
    public byte? RowStatus { get; set; }

    public string RoleName { get; set; }
}
```

Razor

```
@foreach(var item in Model._ModuleModelList.Where(x => x.Level == 1))
{
    <ul style="display: block;">
        <li><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            <label>
                @if (item.Level == 1)
                {
                    <input id="node-0-1" data-id="custom-1" type="checkbox" name="Module" value="@item.ModuleID"@(Model._ModuleModel.ModuleID)? "checked":"">
                    @item.ModuleName

                }
            </label>
            @foreach (var lavel1 in Model._ModuleModelList.Where(x => x.ParentModuleID == item.ModuleID))
            {
                <ul>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                        <label>
                            <input id="node-0-1-1" data-id="custom-1-1" type="checkbox" name="Module" value="@lavel1.ModuleID"@(Model._ModuleModel.ModuleID)? "checked":"">
                            @lavel1.ModuleName
                        </label>
                        @foreach (var lavel2 in Model._ModuleModelList.Where(x => x.ParentModuleID == lavel1.ModuleID))
                        {
                            <ul>
                                <li><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                    <label>
                                        <input id="node-0-1-1-1" data-id="custom-1-1-1" type="checkbox" name="Module" value="@lavel2.ModuleID"@(Model._ModuleModel.ModuleID)? "checked":"">
                                        @lavel2.ModuleName
                                    </label>
                                    @foreach (var lavel3 in Model._RightsModelList.Where(x => x.ModuleId == lavel2.ModuleID))
                                    {
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>
                                                <label>

                                                    <input id="node-0-1-1-1-1" data-id="custom-1-1-1-1" type="checkbox" name="Right" value="@lavel3.RightID"@(Model._RightsModel.RightID)? "checked":"">
                                                    @lavel3.RightName
                                                </label>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    }
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        }
                    </li>
                </ul>
            }
        </li>
    </ul>
}
```